# The player from the last game is shooting in the new game

Tags: java

I created a shooter game. When I lose and press play again the game starts.  But if I press spacebar to shoot besides the current player who is shooting, there are launched another bullets from the position where the last game ended. If I lose and play again it is shooting from 3 positions, from the current and from the last 2 games. I suppose that somewhere I did not dispose the player or something.

[image] 

The X is position where I was when the last game ended

```
private static ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
//constructor
public GameFrame(){
    setFocusable(true);
    addMouseListener(new MouseInput());
    mainTimer = new Timer(12,this);
    mainTimer.start();
    setupScene();
private void setupScene()
{
    player = new Player(300,520);
    enemyCount = 10;
    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapt(player));
    startGame();
}

private void clearScene(){
    score=0;
    level=1;
    player = null;
    missiles.clear();
    enemies.clear();
}

public void startGame() {
    for (int i = 0; i < enemyCount; i++) {
        addEnemy(new Enemy(rand.nextInt(600), -rand.nextInt(600)));
    }
}
public void checkEnd(){
    if(enemies.size() == 0 ){
        level++;
        enemies.clear();
        missiles.clear();
        startGame();
    }
}
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(State == STATE.GAME) {
        player.update();
        repaint();

        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
            Enemy tempEnemy = enemies.get(i);
            tempEnemy.update();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < missiles.size(); i++) {
            Missile m = missiles.get(i);
            m.update();
            repaint();
        }
    }
    checkGameOver();
    checkEnd();
}

private void checkGameOver() {
  for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
    if (enemies.get(i).getY() >= 570)
    {
        State = STATE.GAME_OVER;
        clearScene();
        setupScene();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `setUpScene()` in a loop if the game is over, this doesn't look right.

Comment: the enemies are cleared, the problem is with the player, it is cleared from the map but in the next game when i shoot there are launching bullets from the position where the player was in the last game

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that and updated my comment, I think your `checkGameOver` method looks incorrect. Why call those methods several times in that loop?

Comment: well when i called setupScene() and clearScene() out of the loop there are falling enemies an the all screen, i am kind of confused

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is, that the KeyListener is still there for the old player so the old player-instance is still active.

So I would suggest to
a) save the KeyAdapt instance somewhere
b) remove the KeyAdapt instance with a call to removeKeyListener when you set the player to null.